# The definition of 'Data' Asset Type under the Center for Internet Security (CIS) Controls v8, RAMv2, CDMv2

Tags: cis-framework

I am looking for what CIS defines as each of the Asset Types.  They have each of the asset types within the glossaries of their documents (Controls, Risk Assessment Methodology, Community Defence Profile) but i havent been able to see what they specifically mean by 'Data'.  Even within their Privacy Guide.  It is just obliquely stated.  Is there a definitative reference they point too?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the NIST Privacy Framework Glossary will do for now:

Data - A representation of information, including digital and non-digital formats.

Comment: But this isn't the CIS definition, as you asked. So I'm not sure how this answers your question. Why do you need an explicit definition? Common words do not require definition.

Comment: To ensure that CIS has used the same taxonomy when dividing 'things' into 'categories' such as users, devices, data, etc.